# What acts play somber, soulful blues like Cassandra Wilson's cover of "Death Letter Blues" (True Detective season 3 theme)?

Tags: soundtrack, genre, blues, soul

Cassandra Wilson is mostly a jazz musician, but recorded a cover of "Death Letter Blues" (used as the [theme song for True Detective season 3](https://youtu.be/AFvnT0X9eFQ)) that -- unlike Son House's original -- is rich with a somber electric bass line, complimented with slide guitar and her soulful singing. Unfortunately, nothing else on her New Moon Daughter album sounds like it.

Are there any acts that consistently play in this dark, soulful, slow tempo Delta Blues style?

Comment: Might this be better phrased as an "identify this genre" question ?  You could then use the genre(s)  to search Spotify etc.

Comment: That would be a good alternative question, but since my goal is to identify an actual act, the question as posted is more direct. If this question remains unanswered, though, your suggestion would make for a good follow-up question.

Comment: These may be too jazz oriented for you, but they are fairly consistent:
Pyeng Threadgill 
Nnenna Freelon
Dee Dee Bridgewater
Melody Gardot